# Generator functions with synchronous method calls

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Can you use yield to make a method call that is not async?

**Generator Function**

```
function* generatorFunction () {
    var asyncResult = yield doSomethingAsync();
    console.log(asyncResult)

    var nonAsyncResult = yield doSomethingNonAsync();
    console.log(nonAsyncResult)
}
```

**Supporting Methods**

```
function doSomethingAsync() {
    axios
    .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
    .then(response => {
        generatorInstance.next(response.data);
    })
}

function doSomethingNonAsync(){
    generatorInstance.next("foo");
}
```

**Result**

First `console.log` works as expected, logs results of axios call, then I get the following javascript error

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Generator is already running
>       at generatorFunction.next ()
>       at doSomethingNonAsync (async.html:16)
>       at generatorFunction (async.html:23)
>       at generatorFunction.next ()
>       at axios.get.then.response (async.html:11)

https://jsfiddle.net/dsquod1m/

Comment: No, not with something as simple as that. Your `doSomethingAsync()` example doesn't even have a `return` statement.  That said, it's via generator behavior (wrapped up in more boilerplate) that `async` and `await` work under the hood.

Comment: Why are you doing your own coroutines rather than just using `async` functions or writing a pump function to drive them like one?

Comment: @Pointy, Sorry for my ignorance. Whats the difference between using `return` to supply a "response value" in a yielded method and calling `.next()` with a "response value" as the parameter

Comment: You cannot call `next()` until the previous `next()` returned something. If you could do this, execution would be out of order ...

Comment: Well without `yeild` or `return` (and `yield` only works in generators of course) a function will just return `undefined`. Thus `yieild doSomethingAsync()` is effectively `yield undefined;` (except for the function side-effect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issues have nothing to do with sync or async call. The problem is that you're trying to run `next()` from generator:

```
var nonAsyncResult = yield doSomethingNonAsync(); // this contains another next() call
```

Generators cannot self-call themselves from their internals.

Answer (score 0):

I think the procedure is like this. The generator starts running, and when the function after the yield finishes executing, the generator pauses, but when `generatorinstance.next` is called, the generator is still running, it's not stopped, so it throws an error.
If the yield is followed by an asynchronous function, the generator will have paused when `Generatorinstance.next` is called, so it works well.